# Simple AJAX call to database from aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

So having a bit trouble figuring out how to successfully use AJAX to call a method and retrieve data. I am being asked to do this, not exactly sure why but I would usually just handle all this stuff in a MVC environment in the Controller. But for now I am asked to do this in AJAX. I have a ASPX file that I am simply trying to see work so i can move on. So far none of the stack overflow suggestions helped.

Here's what I currently have:

.ASPX/source

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

          $("#go").click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "Default.aspx/ItemData",
                  processData: true,
                  data: {},
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function () { alert("yay") },
                  error: function () { alert("nay") }
              });
          });

      });

 </script>
```

And then in my Default.aspx.cs file I have a method 'ItemData'

```
[WebMethod]
public static NextCrew.Models.Item ItemData(string cookieID)
{
    Item item = new Item();
    item.name = "Fred";
    item.idx = 1;
    item.completed = 1;
    return item;
}
```

(Item is simple a Model withg 3 properties: Name(string), idx(int) and completed(int) )

I am having a hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong here. Can someone please write an example of what I am trying to do? Just a simple GET request that I can return an object (once I get done testing I want to be able to connect to a DB so I need it to be an object) using AJAX.

I can't tell what I am doing wrong but I have some ideas:

1)maybe my url in the ajax isn't formatted properly?

2)do i need to pass anything into data if I have a parameter?

3)is my get method in the correct .cs file?

**UPDATE**

I was informed I need to have a special class to handle this. I tried to then make a .asmx and the AJAX is still not being called. Hoping someone sees an error that I missed.

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "WebService2.asmx/GetItems",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: 'Json',
                success: function (result) {
                    // alert(result.d);
                    $.each(result.d, function (index, ele) {

                        $("#Myddl").append("<option value='" + ele.value + "'>" + ele.text + "</option>");
                    })
                }
            });

        })
    </script>
```

.asmx

```
public class WebService2 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public List<Item2> GetItems()
        {
            //suppose data comes from database
            var result = new List<Item2>() { 
              new Item2{ text="one",value="one"},
              new Item2{ text="two",value="two"},
              new Item2{ text="three",value="three"}

            };
            return result;
        }

        public class Item2
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say "what am I doing wrong?" what do you mean? what do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: Good question. What I mean by that is, the error function gets called when this runs. *What do I want to happen*: Well I want it to run through the method and return the object into the success function as an alert(). If that makes sense. I'm just trying to see this work is all.

Comment: What I would do is to use the Chrome debugging tool to check the server error (it may be a 404 0r a 500). Or simply browse with google to your webmethod data, you should be able to see the error clearly if it is a server error...

Comment: Ok, you need to put the webmethod in a special webservice file, usually with extension .asmx... you shoud be able to create one using Visual Studio normal "Add New Item..." menu. In that file (.asmx.cs) you can create WebMethods.

Comment: Ok so i figured out part of my problem - I needed a `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` and now it's getting called BUT I am getting a 500 error now. Do you have any idea what that could be?

Comment: WebServices need an extra attribute on top of the main class to be consumable from javascript: `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`. Have a look at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/liBRary/bb532367(v=vs.90).aspx
That should be the only thing missing as far as I can tell :)